# How to iterate DataSet<Row> of records more that 5L in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

We are fetching records from table more than 5.5L and creating spark DataSet. Now, we want to write file and when we are using `dataSet.collectAsList` then spark job is terminated and giving below error:

Driver stacktrace:

```
19/04/12 12:43:33 INFO DefaultLifecycleProcessor: Stopping beans in phase 0
19/04/12 12:43:33 INFO AnnotationMBeanExporter: Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
19/04/12 12:43:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 failed: collectAsList at BuildFinalDataSetProcessing.java:130, took 234.918368 s
19/04/12 12:43:33 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
19/04/12 12:43:33 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext already stopped.
19/04/12 12:43:33 INFO DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
19/04/12 12:43:34 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called.
```

How can we iterate DataSet?

Answer (score 0):

> we are using dataSet.collectAsList

Don't do this. Write the dataset using `dataset.write`.

Comment: ok thanks .Actually I am new in Spark .But I need to modified some column value of row , so before write we need to modified some column value so how can we do that ?

Comment: What kind of modification you want to do ? you can do with withcolumn method , or you can register as a temporary table and write sql query to modify rows.

Comment: @sauravranjan This isn't the forum to teach you spark step by step. Read this book: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-fundamentals-spark-application-development.html